# How can i convert this query to Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i want to convert this sql Query to Linq in C#

```
 select distinct(E.Nombre), E.Puesto,E.Telefono,E.Correo1,E.Correo2
    from dbo.CCEscalaMando E
```

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYGkl.jpg)
How can i do?

Comment: Show some sample input and expected output.

Comment: i just edit the post and add a image

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start off with your SQL:

```
select distinct(E.Nombre), E.Puesto,E.Telefono,E.Correo1,E.Correo2
    from dbo.CCEscalaMando E
```

Which technically is valid, but the way it is written makes it look like it is doing something that it isn't.  The above will execute the exact same as

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.Nombre, E.Puesto, E.Telefono, E.Correo1, E.Correo2
FROM dbo.CCEscalaMando E
```

The parenthesis make it look like you are calling a distinct function, when in reality you are just using SELECT DISTINCT, and the first column you just put in parenthesis for no reason.  You could put all the columns in parenthesis, but it has effect on the distinct:

```
select distinct (E.Nombre), (E.Puesto), (E.Telefono), (E.Correo1), (E.Correo2)
from dbo.CCEscalaMando E
```

Now that we've removed your confusing bit, it's easy to convert:

```
dbContext.CCEscalaMando.Select(e=>new {
  e.Nombre,
  e.Puesto,
  e.Telefono,
  e.Correo1,
  e.Correo2})
.Distinct();
```

Comment: .Distinct() it doesnt works, the sentence show all data without disctinc :(

Comment: this show 557 rows var lista = agp.CC15_EscalaMando().Select
  (e => new{
  e.Nombre,
  e.Puesto,
  e.Telefono,
  e.Correo1,
  e.Correo2})
  .Distinct().Select(
  x => new UsuarioNotificacionViewModel{
    Nombre = x.Nombre,
    Puesto = x.Puesto,
    Telefono = x.Telefono,
    Correo1 = x.Correo1,
    Correo2 = x.Correo2
  }).OrderBy(x => x.Nombre);

and the sql Query 555 rows

Comment: It is possible that your fields either have trailing spaces in them, or one or more rows have mixed case.  In SQL these would be combined, but not in LINQ by default.